# How to discard/coalesce repeated AWT events?

Tags: java, swing, timer, awt, edt

When a user does some action (such as click a button), I need to display the status in the JLabel. This status needs to disappear after 2 seconds. I use the following for that.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

However, it is possible that the user clicks the button many times and this timer is triggered multiple times. This has an undesirable effect. When a button is clicked 3 times for instances.

0th second: 1st click : label disppear at 2nd second

1st second: 2nd click : label disppear at 3rd second

2nd second: 3rd click : label disppear at 4th second

Here, the label needs to disappear after the 4th second but will disappear after 2nd second. Therefore, I want this label to be hidden with a delay of 2s after only the **last event**

To handle this, I use an atomic counter.

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

Each task is given a unique 'taskCounter' using counter.incrementAndGet()

.

```
  Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (counter.get() == taskCounter) {
                infoLabel.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
```

The above is only executed if it is the last event that has been triggered. Ensuring that, my label stays visible at least 2 seconds after the last event.

Is there a better way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: Please note: your question actually translates to "can you help me improve this code" ... and such questions better go to codereview.stackexchange.com. Here we help with "concrete" problems ...

Comment: What's about `Timer.setRepeats(false)`?

Comment: @Jägermeister actually, my question is more like are there existing methods to deal with this problem. Am I reinventing the wheel?

Comment: You could keep track of how long the `Timer` has been running, on each tick, make a determination about what you should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two instances of `java.swing.Timer`, let `t1` fire at some some nominal rate that is less than two seconds. Let the `ActionListener` for `t1` update the `label` and invoke `restart()` on `t2`, which should have an initial delay of two seconds. Let the `ActionListener` for `t2` `stop()` itself and invoke `label.setVisible(false)`.

Comment: Invoke `t1.start()` in the button's `ActionListener`. If this does not work in the context of your actual program, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that focus on your approach.

Comment: Ok, cool! Now I work with only one timer. I always restart it on the button click and then set the label to visible. So the timer always has to hide the label after 2 seconds. The overlap is not possible.